# Angular guard not redirecting to specific page due to exception

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router-guards

So I'm trying to implement a basic guard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
          state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
return this.userService.isBoardMember().pipe(
  map(data => {
    if (data === false) {
      this.router.navigate(['main']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  })
);
}
```

The `isBoardMember` method looks like this:

```
getUserDetails(): Observable<User> {
this.requestUrl = `${configs.bgwssApi}v1/bics/${this.bic}/tcifs/${this.tcif}/users`;
return this.http.get<User>(this.requestUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

isBoardMember(): Observable<boolean> {
return this.getUserDetails().pipe(map(data => {
  return (data.userRole === 'BOARD_MEMBER');
}));
}
```

`handleError` method:

```
  private handleError(e: HttpErrorResponse) {
let errorMessage = '';
if (e.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
  // Client side error received
  errorMessage = `Error getting user occurred: ${e.error.message}`;
} else {
  // Server side error received
  errorMessage = `Error getting user from server, code: ${e.status}, message: ${e.message}`;
}
console.error(errorMessage);
return throwError(errorMessage);
```

}

The problem is that when `getUserDetails` http request returns 404 error(doesn't find the specific user), `isBoardMember` method doesn't return anything so my guard is not properly redirecting to `main` page as it should - instead it just loads an empty page with no url. Need some help solving this issue.

Comment: can you show the `this.handleError` method?

Comment: Added to my question

Comment: Change `handleError`'s return value to `false` and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add another `catchError`, because you are throwing an error on 404 in your `handleError` method.

It feels like the `isBoardMember` is the right place for that. If you feel like it should be in the guard, you can add the logic there:

So either in the Service:

```
isBoardMember(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.getUserDetails().pipe(
    map(data => data.userRole === 'BOARD_MEMBER'),
    catchError(() => of(false))
  );
}
```

Or in the guard:

```
constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {}

canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
  return this.userService.isBoardMember().pipe(
    catchError(() => of(false)),
    map(data => data || this.router.createUrlTree(['main']))
  );
}
```

I'm using `createUrlTree` because that's the recommended way to do a redirect from a guard